# WebSphere ClassNotFoundException when invoking WebService after startup (but not later)

Tags: java, websphere, classpath, webservice-client, classnotfoundexception

**Update**: The `ClassNotFoundException` only occurs if I try to use the web service immediately after starting the application. If I wait (for some unknown event/duration) the application will work. I would like to know what it is that I need to wait for.

---

**Problem**: My application fails because a class that does exist is not found by a classloader.

**More info**:

The class that cannot be found is `com.sun.xml.stream.ZephyrParserFactory`.

In my EAR I have the `sjsxr.jar`. This jar contains the class `com.sun.xml.stream.ZephyrParserFactory`

The EAR also contains `MyApp.jar`, which contains the EJB entry points for the application. The `MyApp.jar` manifest references all the needed jars, including `sjsxr.jar`

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.1
Created-By: 1.5.0_18 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Built-By: GMM Development Team
Class-Path: aopalliance-1.0.jar commons-codec-1.4.jar commons-collecti
 ons-3.1.jar commons-lang-2.1.jar commons-logging-1.1.1.jar ehcache-co
 re-2.1.0.jar ehcache-spring-annotations-1.1.2.jar joda-time-1.6.1.jar
  log4j-1.2.16.jar org.springframework.context.support-3.0.4.RELEASE.j
 ar sjsxr.jar slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar spring-aop
 -3.0.4.RELEASE.jar spring-asm-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar spring-beans-3.0.4.RE
 LEASE.jar spring-context-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar spring-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.
 jar spring-expression-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar spring-jdbc-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
  spring-tx-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar swiftVal.jar velocity-1.5.jar vm-startup
 .jar xbean.jar
```

The application contains web services client code generated by WebSphere's `wsimport` tool. When the application attempts to invoke this code, the following exception is thrown:

```
EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method 
  "messageIn" on bean "BeanId(MyApp#ejb.jar#NodeEJB, null)". 
Exception data: javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider
  com.sun.xml.stream.ZephyrParserFactory not found
    at javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils$7.run(StAXUtils.java:327)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:202)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.getXMLInputFactory_perClassLoader(StAXUtils.java:323)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.getXMLInputFactory(StAXUtils.java:78)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.createXMLStreamReader(StAXUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.XMLUtils.toOM(XMLUtils.java:596)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.XMLUtils.toOM(XMLUtils.java:581)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DescriptionBuilder.buildOM(DescriptionBuilder.java:97)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:90)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.populateAxisConfiguration(DeploymentEngine.java:641)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.deployment.WASAxis2ConfigurationBuilder.loadAxisCfg(WASAxis2ConfigurationBuilder.java:492)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.deployment.WASAxis2ConfigurationBuilder.loadAxisClientConfiguration(WASAxis2ConfigurationBuilder.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.client.WSClientConfigurationFactory.getConfigContext(WSClientConfigurationFactory.java:271)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.client.WSClientConfigurationFactory.getClientConfigurationContext(WSClientConfigurationFactory.java:236)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:92)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.DescriptionFactory.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactory.java:76)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegate.<init>(ServiceDelegate.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.Provider.createServiceDelegate(Provider.java:59)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:67)
    at my.generated.Web_Service.<init>(Web_Service.java:44)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.stream.ZephyrParserFactory
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:136)
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    ... 101 more
```

I have confirmed half a dozen times that the class, jar and manifest are correct before and after deployment.

I have also tried renaming the `sjsxr.jar` to avoid any potential eclipses but the problem does not go away.

I am using WebSphere 7.0.0.11 ND

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you post the MyApp.jar's manifest entry for sjsxr.jar?

Comment: Edited the question with manifest added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a long time since I used java, and only touched WebSphere briefly, but maybe [this](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/verified/packaging.html) will help? If you are having problems locating the jar file using the manifest, try packaging it in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder in the jar. It should be found implicitly without having to reference it in the manifest, assuming I read the info on the linked page correctly.

You also may want to have a look at [this WebSphere link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/ccli_classloading.html), about halfway down the page under the heading "Referencing classes within the EAR file".

Comment: Thank you Will. The WEB-INF/lib approach is only utilised by WAR files. However, this link has prompted me to try moving the classpath info from the manifest of the internal JAR to the EAR itself. Note, this app is built using a build system that has been working for 4 or 5 years, so I expect the EAR is already valid. But we'll see ...

Comment: Good luck. As I said, been a long time since I did any substantial java development (like, EJB 1.0 timeframe), so my knowledge on this is limited. Google turned up a number of other decent links if the above doesn't fix it.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the problem persists.

Comment: Can't believe I missed this ... look at the 5th line of your class path you posted. Unless it was a typo in your post, you have `sjsxp.jar`, not `sjsxr.jar` in your class path.

Comment: At various times I was manually modifying different manifests. Yes that was a typo. Usually this manifest is created by the ant build. This is not a classpath issue per se. I'm updating the issue with more info.

Comment: Awarded correct answer because your info is good. However the true issue was something much more sinister. See my response for more info.